# Keep random values from matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

I have a matrix, which contains N entries each with M rows. Each row contains of 0s and 1s. I want to create a second matrix with the same size, but in each row only one 1 should be left, every other value should be 0. Which value should be 1 should be chosen randomly.

E.g.:

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
->
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation of [find](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/find.html) and [randperm](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/randperm.html)

```
%//preallocate the output matrix
out = zeros(size(a));

%for each row, take a random sample from the indices holding value 1     
for i = 1:size(a,1)
     temp2 = find(a(i,:));
     out(i,temp2(randperm(numel(temp2))(1))) = 1;
end
```

Watch the code in action [here](http://ideone.com/hAWZGg)